# awk: Extracting file name from full path

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have a listing for a file like this:

```
-rw-r--r--   3 knsdkls users  336207616 2014-11-10 07:15 /hive/some/thing/path/location/data/plants/zombies/Filename.txt
```

From this, I would like to extract the file size and the filename.

I tried awk:

```
awk '{print $5,$NF}'
```

Which gives:

```
336207616  /hive/some/thing/path/location/data/plants/zombies/Filename.txt
```

I would like:

```
336207616  Filename.txt
```

Please guide me.
Further, the number of sub-directories in the file path is not constant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F" +|/" '{print $5,$NF}'
336207616 Filename.txt
```

Just add `/` as separator.

Comment: @FenderBender It just change the separator to `" +"` one ore more space and `/`.  This will then divide all fields using space or slash. Last field would then be after last `/`.  You can add many separators like this `-F"a|g| "` (a,g or space), or like this `-F"[ag ]"`

Comment: One thing to remember:  this only works if no other field contains slashes — which should hold in this case.

Comment: @ua2b I know.  And since its a directory listing, it will not have slashes other place. (not in owner or group)

Comment: @Jotne I only wanted to prevent others from this pitfall.  Otherwise I think this ist the most elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Through awk's `split` function.

```
$ awk '{n=split($NF,a,"/");print $5,a[n]}' file
336207616 Filename.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `split($NF,a,"/")` splits the last field according to the delimiter `/` and store the splitted parts into an array `a`. The total number of splitted parts are stored into an variable called `n`. So for this case, the variable `n` contains `10`.
- `print $5,a[n]` This prints the fifth field plus the last element stored in the array `a`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` function

```
$ awk '{gsub(/.*\//, "", $NF); print $5,$NF}' input
336207616 Filename.txt
```

- `gsub(/.*\//, "", $NF)` subtitutes  anything, `.*` till the `/` with null string `""`
- `print $5,$NF` prints the fifth and last field